# How do I post JSON to a web API method?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, api, stock

I want to send a JSON string via API, and then parse the JSON in code.  I don't want Magento to try to convert my JSON parameter to a PHP object.

I'm trying to add this to the stock registry API.  Here's the code that I've added.

**webapi.xml**

```
<route url="/V1/products/stockItems/update/" method="POST">
    <service class="Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface" method="updateStockItems"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="Magento_CatalogInventory::cataloginventory"/>
    </resources>
</route>
```

**StockRegistryInterface.php**

```
public function updateStockItems($stockItems);
```

**StockRegistry.php**

```
public function updateStockItems($stockItems)
{
   // do stuff
}
```

I'm posting to `http://magento.test/rest/V1/products/stockItems/update` using Postman.

Here is my request address and headers.

[image]

[image]

Here's my JSON body

```
{
   "stockItems": [
      {
        "item_id": 1,
        "product_id": 1,
        "stock_id": 1,
        "qty": 15
      },
      {
        "item_id": 2,
        "product_id": 2,
        "stock_id": 2,
        "qty": 15
      }
   ]
}
```

I'm getting the error

```
[2019-03-06 18:22:44] main.CRITICAL: Report ID: webapi-5c800ff4b4623;
Message: Class  does not exist {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: -1):
Report ID: webapi-5c800ff4b4623; Message: Class  does not exist at 
/var/www/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Webapi/
ErrorProcessor.php:205, ReflectionException(code: -1): 
Class  does not exist at /var/www/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/
Webapi/ServiceInputProcessor.php:162)"} []
```

How do I get Magento to let me pass my JSON into `updateStockItems` without trying to convert it to a Magento object?

**Update**

I can get it to work by passing my JSON as a string and then parsing that string into JSON in the PHP code.  If I use the following as the body of my request, it works.  But that seems like a dirty workaround.  **Is there a better way of doing it?**

`{ "stockItems": "[ {\"sku\": \"SKU-1234\", \"quantity\": 1234}, {\"sku\": \"SKU-5678\", \"quantity\": 5678} ]" }`

And here's my PHP code (`getStockItemBySku` is an existing Magento function within `StockRegistry.php`)

```
public function updateStockItems($stockItems)
{
    $json = json_decode($stockItems, true);
    $updatedItemCount = 0;
    foreach ($json as $productJson)
    {            
        $sku = $productJson['sku'];
        $quantity = $productJson['quantity'];
        if ($sku !== NULL && $quantity != NULL)
        {
            $stockItem = $this->getStockItemBySku($sku);
            if ($stockItem !== NULL)
            {
                $stockItem->setQty($quantity);
                $this->stockItemRepository->save($stockItem);
                $updatedItemCount++;
            }
        }
    }
    return $updatedItemCount;
}
```

Comment: it should be `rest` not test

Comment: Sorry, typo.  I updated it.  It's `rest` in my actual code.

Comment: you should include in your header the Content-type of your request, it should be `Content-Type: application/json`

Comment: I've got that in my header.  I'm using Postman to send requests, and I've got `Content-Type: application/json` as one of my headers in the request.

Comment: I updated my question to show the request headers.

Comment: can you show us the PHP code wherein you parse the string to json

Comment: Sure.  I updated the post.

Comment: how about the body of the post , is it on json type as well?

Comment: Yes, it is.  I updated the post to show it.

Comment: Whoops, I posted my updated string version of the JSON in the screenshot.  I fixed it.

Comment: that is actually the JSON format it is not a string. great for you at least it is working now. enjoy coding

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope you don't have the intention to "hack" Magento core files. I recommend to create your own classes / interfaces for that!

Anyway if you are implementing a custom method `updateStockItems` for a webapi which updates more stockitems with a single request you should take care of the right method signature: You are expecting an array of stock items, therefore your input parameter should be of that type.

Your interface:

```
/**
 * 
 * @param \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\Data\StockItemInterface[] $stockItems
 * @return int
 * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException
 */
public function updateStockItems(\Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\Data\StockItemInterface[] $stockItems);
```

Your method implementation:

```
/**
 * 
 * @param \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\Data\StockItemInterface[] $stockItems
 * @return int
 * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException
 */
public function updateStockItems(\Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\Data\StockItemInterface[] $stockItems)
{
    foreach ($stockItems as $stockItem){
        //do whatever with your stock item
    }
};
```

Please take care to use only parameter in your JSON objects which match the used interfaces, in this example `\Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\Data\StockItemInterface`. So putting there some key `sku` doesn't make sense and should either be ignored by Magento or give you an error in the API call.

Here is the documentation about the usage of custom webservices.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/service-contracts/service-to-web-service.html

Comment: Well I did have the intention to hack one of the core files, but since I've been called out now, I guess I'll do it the right way and make a module.

Answer (score 1):

The rest API address you are using seems not correct. Have a look at this page, under the cataloginventory section:

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/rest/list.html#cataloginventory

As you can see the available URLs are different from the one you are using.

The correct one you should be using is this one:

```
PUT    /V1/products/:productSku/stockItems/:itemId
```

And you can update one stock at a time, so you need to call the API for each product you want to update.

Comment: The API address I'm using is one I created (see my webapi.xml).  I'll ultimately be updating hundreds or thousands of items, so I'm trying to do it as a single request, rather than issuing a thousand requests, to cut down on overhead.

Comment: Please check the webapi.xml in this example, it is a little different from yours: https://inchoo.net/magento-2/magento-2-custom-api/. The same is here: https://www.thirdandgrove.com/creating-custom-rest-api-magento2

Comment: Do you mean the `<?xml>` and `<routes>` tags?  I have those in my actual webapi file.  That part in my question is just an excerpt.  I think my webapi file is OK because I can change the type of the parameter in my `updateStockItems` method and I get different errors, so Magento is finding the route correctly.